# Magento2 - What is the purpose of a Data Interface?

Tags: magento2, api

I am unable to find a solid definition or understanding of the purpose or role of a `data interface` in `Magento2 API` Architecture.

Answer (score 6):

**Data interfaces**

Data interfaces are used to maintain the integrity of the data, data interfaces defines all the setters and getters for the related entity. So even if there is any changes in the model or business logic you will always get consistent data. Data interfaces resides in VendorName\ModuleName\Api\Data, so in all the modules you can found data interfaces in Api/Data folders, related model need to implement these interfaces and provide the setters, getters deffinition.

**Interfaces**

Repository interfaces give access to persistent data entities. interfaces have the following methods:

`save(data entity interface):` Creates a new record if no id present, otherwise updates an existing record with the specified id.

`get(id):` Performs a database lookup by id and returns a data entity interface (such as CustomerInterface or AddressInterface).

`getList(search criteria):` Performs a search for all data entities matching the search criteria and returns a search results interface to give access to the set of matches.

`delete(data entity interface):` Deletes the specified entity (the key is in the entity).

`deleteById(id):` Deletes the specified entity when you only have the key for the entity.

1. 3rd party module should operate with your module's
   classes/interfaces marked as `@api`, not necessarily service contract
   interfaces, but preferably. If interface is requested in
   dependencies, Magento object manager resolves actual model to be
   instantiated according to preferences declared in `di.xml` (since
   interface itself cannot be instantiated).
2. It is recommended to declare service contract interfaces, read about
   benefits here and in official docs.
3. Is answered above (model implements interface). You should always
   use `interfaces` if available, even if those are defined in your
   module. This allows to manage complexity by limiting number of
   dependencies between classes/modules.

Comment: your response is really helpful in understanding the data Api. Thanks, DineshArumugam